# How do I implement single sign on Django with Azure Ad. Any clues are highly appreciated

Tags: python, azure, django-rest-framework, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

Hi I am creating a web application in Django that integrates with Azure AD. My goal is to enable single sign on capability to my web application and I'm not sure about where to start. Please help with good references. Djangorestframework integration will be helpful

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60008677/how-should-i-be-implementing-user-sso-with-aad-in-a-django-application-using-th)

If you want to implement on **server**

- Make sure to Add `simple_sso.sso_server`  to  `INSTALLED_APPS`, Create  an instance of `simple_sso.sso_server.server.Server` and include value`get_urls` method

If you want to implement on **Client**

- Create a new instance of  `simple_sso.sso_server.models.Consumer`  on the  **Server**. add `SIMPLE_SSO_SECRET` and `SIMPLE_SSO_KEY` provided by server model `simple_sso.sso_server.models.Client`
- Add `SIMPLE_SSO_SERVER`with correct url to root `simple_sso.sso_server.urls`where you include on server  and add `simple_sso.sso_client.urls` on client.

To configure setting's in [python](https://django-auth-adfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/azure_ad_config_guide.html#step-2-configuring-settings-py) Replace your AUTH_ADFS with this.

To do so, login to your ADFS server and click the relying party trust created with the Django app and check all the details regarding the federation properties like data XML link, claims and attributes passing rules, etc ..

For more information in detail, please **refer** below links:

[GitHub - divio/django-simple-sso](https://github.com/divio/django-simple-sso)

[Implementing Single Sign On (SSO) using Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662348/implementing-single-sign-on-sso-using-django)

[python - How to implement single sign-on django auth in azure ad? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62982266/how-to-implement-single-sign-on-django-auth-in-azure-ad)